# Run bulk chmod for all sub-folder .git/ in each project

Tags: linux, ssh, git, chmod

I know how to CHMOD for single folder such like `chmod 700 .git/`, however in my server it has multiple project, each of them contains .git/ folder. From a report of repo-lookout.org, they suggest to disable access to `.git/` repository, I wish to apply bulk chmod 700 to all `.git/` folder (but not including sub-folder inside `.git`)

Running `find */.git/ -type d` will return a list such like:

```
site1/.git/objects/b3
site1/.git/info
site1/.git/refs
site1/.git/refs/heads
site1/.git/refs/remotes
site1/.git/refs/remotes/origin
site1/.git/refs/tags
site1/.git/hooks
site2/.git/
site2/.git/logs
site2/.git/logs/refs
site2/.git/logs/refs/heads
site2/.git/logs/refs/remotes
site2/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin
site2/.git/branches
site2/.git/objects
site2/.git/objects/93
```

How to apply CHMOD 700 to only those pattern `site1/.git`, `site2.git`?

Thanks,

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable in many ways, e.g. you can use a regex here:

```bash
find -type d -regex '.*/\.git$'
```

where `.*` is anything, then we match `.git` dir literally and `$` makes sure it's at the end.

Then to `chmod` them you can use e.g. `xargs`:

```bash
find -type d -regex '.*/\.git$' | xargs chmod 700
```